# How to reinstall libjudy on AWS EC2 Amazon Linux instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, php-7.2

I am trying to install a memory profiler (https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler) on my EC2 instance (LAMP stack runnign php 7.2) as we are running in to memory allocation errors. During the installation, I get the following error:

- checking for judy lib... yes, shared
- checking for judy files in default path... not found
- configure: error: Please reinstall the judy distribution
- ERROR: `/tmp/pear/install/memprof/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to reinstall the judy library. I've tried both pecl (No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/libjudy") and yum (No package libjudy available.)

I've searched for ways to install it and have come up empty.

Anyone have any advice?

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I have also asked this question of the memory profile developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following repository

Download latest rpmforge-release rpm from

```
wget https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/dag/redhat/el7/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

Install rpmforge-release rpm:

```
# rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release*rpm
```

Install judy rpm package:

```
# yum install judy judy-devel
```

Comment: Hi - this installation works just fine. But I get the same error about judy files not being in the default path. I think maybe I need the -dev rpm. Any idea where I might find that? Thanks!

Comment: Ok - this works: **# yum install judy-devel**. Thanks!